# How to represent 2 model objects inside the thymeleaf template

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

i am working in this `spring-boot` project and i am returning a `ModelAndView` object from my `controller` method , i have added 2 objects to the `ModelAndView`. this part is working and i want to know how to represent the values inside the `thymeleaf` template.

```
public ModelAndView showEdit(@PathVariable int id,Customer cust,Model model){
    ModelAndView view  = new ModelAndView();
    view.setViewName("editCustom");
    view.addObject("cust",cust);
    view.addObject("log",login);
}
```

inside the `thymeleaf` template.

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/save}" th:object="${cust}" method="post">
 Name:<input type="text" th:field="*{name}" />
```

i can fetch values in `cust` but i dont know how to get values from `login`.
i tried this but its not working.note that all input tags are inside the same form.

```
<input type="text" id="user" name="user" value="${login.uname}"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model you are adding login details as log and in your view your are using login

view.addObject("**log**",login);

versus

**${login.uname}**

Also thymeleaf uses an attribute processor which process attributes prefixed with th. Instead of using value use th:value as follows

```
<input type="text" id="user" name="user" th:value="${log.uname}"/>
```